# question about the setup of proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the beginning of alot of proofs of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$,
We have that $$\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2m)^2}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2r+1)^2}$$

How is the last equality true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\sum_{n\ge1}1/n^2$ we subtract the even-$n$ cases, leaving the sum of odd-$n$ terms, i.e. $n=2r+1,\,r\ge0$. The absolute convergence of each infinite sum legitimates this.

Comment: I downvoted. I don't know why you're talking about $\zeta(2)$. OP just asked about last equality.

Comment: @mathworker21 Fixed.

Comment: thanks, +1, though maybe absolute convergence should be mentioned, if you want to be nitpicky.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a look at the odd terms alone in comparison to the "full" series

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}&=1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{4^2}+\cdots\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n+1)^2}&=1+0+\frac1{3^2}+0+\cdots
\end{align*}

Note that we obtain the second line by substracting the even terms only once. This can be written as

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-\color{red}1\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n)^2}$$

Again this can be further simplied which eventually gives us

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}-1\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^2n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}-\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$$

Thus

> $$\therefore~\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n+1)^2}=\frac34\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac34\zeta(2)$$

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes helps to write out the first several terms of a sum. What you have here is

$$\left(1+{1\over4}+{1\over9}+{1\over16}+{1\over25}+{1\over36}+\cdots \right)-\left({1\over4}+{1\over16}+{1\over36}+\cdots\right)=\left(1+{1\over9}+{1\over25}+\cdots\right)$$

Is that enough to make the last equality clear?